# How to restrict "paste" action to specific TextField in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, textfield

Is there any way to prevent user from "pasting" data to a TextField? 
I've set a `ChangeListener` to it, but I can't find out the way how to distinct between keyboardInput and paste action. One certain thing is:

```
 myChangeListener = (ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    if(Math.abs(newValue.length() - oldValue.length()!=1){
        //definitely paste - entered more than one symbol
    }
 };
```

But user can also paste a single character at one time. This is the scenario I can't catch. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems like a strange thing to want to do, as it would be expected behavior. But you can just override the `paste()` method so that it's a no-op:

```
TextField myTextField = new TextField() {
    @Override
    public void paste() { }
};
```